# Immutable list not adding data

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am using an ImmutableList as follows:

- Referenced the package using Nuget and following is the usage code:

  ```
  using System.Collections.Immutable;

  private ImmutableList<Data> immutableList = ImmutableList.Create<Data>();

  // Write Action

  Action writeAction = (() =>
          {
              Data writeData = new Data();

              // Fill Data type with valid values

              immutableList.Add(writeData);    

          });
  ```

This code above is not adding any data to the Immutable list. It remains empty, I cannot figure out the reason when all the data is valid. Similar code is used to fill other data structures like ConcurrentQueue and ConcurrentBag and it works fine.

Am I missing something in the usage of the immutable list, does it requires correction?
Please note this is a multi-threaded operation, but that can't be an issue, since this data structure is thread safe.

Comment: From where is the writeAction called?

Comment: Actually something like this would do it as the Add method RETURNS a new immutable list with the added data, though it may not be super efficient. And there is a concurrency risk that if more than one Action get run at the same time then data could be lost...                     immutableList = immutableList.Add(writeData);

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As the name suggest list is immutable i.e. you cannot add the item to original list. Under remarks section of [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467185(v=vs.111).aspx) link:

> When you add or remove items from an immutable list copy of the
>   original list is made with the items added or removed, and the
>   original list is unchanged.

---

Also from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456077(v=vs.111).aspx), of Add method documentation:

> It returns a new immutable list with the object added, or the current list if it
>   already contains the specified object.

Add will get you new list reference with item added in it (original list will remain unchanged):

```
immutableList = immutableList.Add(writeData);
```

Answer (score 4):

Immutable list is a list that does not change. Here is a description from MSDN on what it means:

> When you add or remove items from an immutable list copy of the original list is made with the items added or removed, and the original list is unchanged.

This means that every time you perform operation like Add, your original list is not changed, but the new list with added element is returned. This means that you would need to use a code like this to have the correct list:

```
immutableList = immutableList.Add(writeData);
```

This makes me think that you are using it for wrong scenario.

Comment: Thanks i completely missed out that basic part, this behavior is same as that of a string

Answer (score -1):

Create your normal list... Turn it into Array
Use that array to make immutable list... heres my snippet

```
        var result = csvReader.GetRecords<Data>().ToArray();
        return ImmutableList.Create<Data>(result);
```

Answer (score -2):

`ImmutableList immutableList = ImmutableList.Create<string>("data1", "data2");`

This works perfectly for me.

Answer (score -2):

The answers already states that the immutable list is really immutable, when you add items, you must designate the new immutable list from the add operation to the same variable for example.

A possibility for easier use is to wrap the immutable list with a functional container class like the following code, which can be pasted in Linqpad 5 (make sure you hit F4 to add Nuget reference to System.Collections.Immutable and pick the namespace from that assembly).

```
void Main()
{
    var numbersInImmutableList = new ImmutableWrappedList<int>();
    numbersInImmutableList.AddRange(new[] { 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2 }); 
    numbersInImmutableList.AddRange(new[]{ 2, 7, 1, 8, 2, 1, 8 });
    numbersInImmutableList.RemoveAt(2);
    numbersInImmutableList.Dump();  
}

public class ImmutableWrappedList<T>  {
    public ImmutableList<T> _internalList {get; private set; }
    
    public ImmutableWrappedList()
    {
        _internalList = ImmutableList.Create<T>();  
    }
    
    public void Clear() => _internalList.Clear();   
    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> itemsToAdd) => _internalList = _internalList.AddRange(itemsToAdd);
    public void Add(T itemToAdd) => _internalList = _internalList.Add(itemToAdd);
    public void Remove(T itemToAdd) => _internalList = _internalList.Remove(itemToAdd);
    public void RemoveAt(int index) => _internalList = _internalList.RemoveAt(index);
    public void Insert(T itemToAdd, int position) => _internalList = _internalList.Insert(position, itemToAdd);
}
```

[image: Immutable Array wrapping class demo that can be run inside Linqpad 5]